# Magento copied value using Jquery, but getting error like this is a required field

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, magento2

I have added a custom field for example - artist price, the value of which is being copied to price field
but when saving the form, I am still getting error `this is a required field`

The code I am using is like:

```
$("[name='product[artist_price]']").change(function() {
$("[name='product[price]']").val($(this).val());
});
```

what I understand is that since the value is being copied and not filled using the keyboard, it assumes that the field is still empty or something else I am not sure.

also after testing I want to hide the field `product[price]`, so how I can achieve this without getting the validation error.

**Update:**
The complete html code for the target field is like this:

```
<input class="admin__control-text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }" name="product[price]" aria-describedby="notice-G2FT2Q2" id="G2FT2Q2" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `change` try using `input` event

Like this

```
$("[name='product[artist_price]']").on("input", function() {
$("[name='product[price]']").val($(this).val());
});
```

Let us know if it works.

Comment: No It doesn't work. I am getting the same validation error.

Comment: if possible can you show the whole code?? if its a form collection i am afraid hidden fields wont give values unless you show them.

Comment: No - I intend to hide the field, but before that while testing, the field is not hidden, the value is being copied to the target field correctly, even with my code, but as I stated, while saving the form I am getting the validation error as if the field is still empty.

Comment: The field is disabled. Enable while saving the form.

Comment: No It is not disabled. I am able to enter the value in that field. when I enter manually, it is saving without any issue.